# Union of proper subspaces of the same dimension of vector space is not a subspace

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, inner-products

I have a series of very related questions and thoughts on each... Would appreciate insight!!

---

1. Let $E$ be an real inner-product space of dimension $n \geq 2$. Show that $E$ is not the union of finitely many hyperplanes of dimension $n-1$.

Proof: $E \cong \mathbb{R}^n$ and so we can topologize $E$ so that it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. The finitely many hyperplanes, by the same argument, will be homemorphic to a finite product of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Thus $E$ is not the union of finitely many hyperplanes of dimension n-1 because their natural typologies inherited from real space are not equivalent.

remark: I feel a bit sketch about this proof, I mean doesn't the topology we put on $E$ depend on a choice of basis? Does this proof work? What is the regular way to prove this?

---

2. Suppose that $E$ is a finite dimensional vector space over an infinite field. Suppose $U_1,U_2,....,U_n$ are proper subspaces of $E$ of the same dimension. Show that the set-theoretic union $\bigcup_{i=1}^nU_i$ is not a subspace. In particular, it is a proper subset of $E$.

To show that it is not a subspace, would I try to find two elements such that adding them together is not in this union? How would I go about doing this?

Could I prove that it is a proper subset using topological arguements like the first part?

Also, what is the counter example where this isn't true over a finite field? Thanks!!

Also, why do we have to assume that $U_i$'s are all the same dimension?

Maybe I should have split this post up into multiple different posts.. I kept having more questions as I typed it up..

Thanks!!

Comment: It is true that any *finite dimensional* (real) vector space $E$ has a unique Hausdorff topology compatible with the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication. Clearly this topology makes $E$ linearly homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\dim E}$ in the Euclidean topology, and conversely can be obtained through any linear isomorphism $E\cong\mathbb{R}^{\dim E}$. However, you lost me in your argument after this step. Why will the finitely many hyperplanes be homeomorphic to a product of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$s? They will be a union of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: For (1) use that each $U_i$ is a closed set with empty interior,  hence their union has no interior either.
  Statement (2) is false since the $U_i$ could all be the same space.
  For finite fields,  finite vector spaces are finite sets,  so may clearly be writen as the finite union of  the
one-dimensional subspaces generated by each nonzero vector.

Comment: for (2), I think we have to show that the general statement is false, not just the specific case when all the $U_i$ are the same space. Thx on #1 tho!!

Comment: @Tyrone I was thinking that they are a product of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, where the number of products is the number of connected components the union has. I was thinking that whenever the union of two of the spaces has nonempty intersection, then the union will be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. No?

Comment: A math statement is only true when all of its cases are true.  A single counter example is enough to show a statement to be false. However you might want to change the statement, requiring the $U_i$ to be distinct, and this would be a different story!

Comment: If re require the $U_i$ to be distinct, could you think of another proof in this case?

Comment: In case the $U_i$ are not all the same this follows from Problem 24 in "Halmos P. R., Linear Algebra Problem Book, Dolciani Mathematical Expositions 16, 1995".  Look for the solution on page 211.

Comment: Is this book available for free somewhere?

Comment: I am not sure but you may find a discussion of this problem together with a proof in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26/can-a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-be-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces.  Look for the answer given by @SteveD.